# Looping through a list gives me repeation of items, xml serializer

Tags: vb.net, xml-serialization

I have two lists. Both are made of structures I have defined, and this loop is meant to convert the two. I.e., convert and then add to the second list of the other type. Here is what I have:

```
        Dim tempList As New List(Of CameraTemplateProduct)
        tempList.Clear()


        For j As Integer = 0 To EditCamerasNEW.templateList.Count - 1

            'Set up product object.
            Dim temp As New CameraTemplateProduct()

            'equal properties
            temp.Name = EditCamerasNEW.templateList.Item(j).mac
            temp.Bitrate = EditCamerasNEW.templateList.Item(j).bitrate
            temp.CamDate = EditCamerasNEW.templateList.Item(j).camdate
            temp.CamTime = EditCamerasNEW.templateList.Item(j).camtime
            temp.Encoder = EditCamerasNEW.templateList.Item(j).encoder
            temp.FPS = EditCamerasNEW.templateList.Item(j).fps
            temp.Hostname = EditCamerasNEW.templateList.Item(j).hostname
            temp.MD = CBool(EditCamerasNEW.templateList.Item(j).MDen)
            temp.OSD = CBool(EditCamerasNEW.templateList.Item(j).OSD)
            temp.Resolution = EditCamerasNEW.templateList.Item(j).res

            tempList.Add(temp)

        Next

        'Serialize object to a text file.
        Dim x As New XmlSerializer((tempList.GetType))
        x.Serialize(objStreamWriter, tempList)
```

Very straight forward. Copy over each property, then add it to the list. When I'm in the loop, temp's values copy over well. The values are exactly the same as the item in TemplateList. When I step through the loop, tempList is exactly what I expect it to be. Three distinct structures. But after wards I get the exact same number of items, but copies of one of them in my list.

However,  the line *right* after the next loop, the tempList instead is the exact same count as templateList, but each value is exactly the same. So every item has the same name, MD, encoder, etc value.

**What I've tried:** I've tried changing the line after the next to

```
     Dim x As New XmlSerializer((GetType(List(Of CameraTemplateProduct))))
```

but it gives the same result.

What am I doing wrong? Is there anything the "templist.gettype" is doing to cause this?

**EDIT:** 
I have found that the temp  is not changing property values when it loops, so it stays stuck at the first loop values. Is there a better way to clear or set it? I tried setting it to Nothing, but it gave me NULL assignment error.

**EDIT2:** So following the comments, 
I checked to see if the templatelist items were changing. I added a

```
  Dim test = EditCamerasNEW.templateList(j).mac
```

for each loop to see that it changed. The value did change. I set the rest of the "templatelist.item(j).x" to just "templatelist(j)" as above, but it didn't stop it from creating a list of repeated values.

**EDIT3** Tried the below method to no avail. I'm thinking it is possibly when I create the templist of my class. It may not know how to create a list of the product? I will take any help on that.

```
                tempList.Add(New CameraTemplateProduct With {.Name = EditCamerasNEW.templateList(j).mac, _
                                                             .Bitrate = EditCamerasNEW.templateList(j).bitrate, _
                                                             .CamDate = EditCamerasNEW.templateList(j).camdate, _
                                                             .CamTime = EditCamerasNEW.templateList(j).camtime, _
                                                             .Encoder = EditCamerasNEW.templateList(j).encoder, _
                                                             .FPS = EditCamerasNEW.templateList(j).fps, _
                                                             .Hostname = EditCamerasNEW.templateList(j).hostname, _
                                                             .MD = EditCamerasNEW.templateList(j).MDen, _
                                                             .OSD = EditCamerasNEW.templateList(j).OSD, _
                                                             .Resolution = EditCamerasNEW.templateList(j).res})
```

Here's a portion of the CameraTemplateProduct definition. It's pretty normal:

```
Public Class CameraTemplateProduct

Public Shared strhostname As String
Public Shared bOSD As Boolean
Public Shared strbitrate As String
Public Shared strencoder As String
Public Shared bMDen As Boolean  'motion detection enabled
Public Shared strres As String
Public Shared intfps As Integer
Public Shared strcamtime As String
Public Shared strcamdate As String
Public Shared strTemplateName As String

'grab properties
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Name = strTemplateName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        strTemplateName = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Hostname() As String
    Get
        Hostname = strhostname
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        strhostname = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property OSD() As Boolean
    Get
        OSD = bOSD
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
        bOSD = Value
    End Set
End Property

 ' code continues
```

Comment: What `Type` is `templateList`?

Comment: @Michael It's a list of the second custom structure. It's basically a set of strings and integers.

Comment: Is `templateList` a standard collection of that structure though, or is `Item` a method you've written? See, if `temp` isn't changing that tells me the `Item` method isn't getting you a different item on every iteration even when the index changes.

Comment: Good point, it's just a list(of customstructure). That may be where I'm going wrong. I'll check it out.

Comment: Is there some additional code in this method you're not including?

Comment: Just two lines. It's where I find the path to write the xml file to.